# How do I resolve an error of this form (\cftchapleader undefined. \renewcommand{\cftchapleader})

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I am working on a thesis proposal using a predefined Tex style and I get this error each time i compile

Comment: As always on the site, please post a full but minimal example so we know what it is you mare doing. As it is now we have no idea

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Since your question is about "an error of this form", my suggestion is: go to the line that latex shows that this error occures... and change `\renewcommand` to `\newcommand`... (But keep in mind it could possibly not offer something because it is based on a different document class... So you should possibly comment out this definition)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. To answer your question it is necessary to know which predefined TeX style you are using. Can you add the name and a link to your question? Also, as @daleif said, it would be very helpful if you can prepare a small document (as small as possible while still being complete) that can be used to reproduce the error.

Comment: @reviewers: maybe we can leave this question open a bit longer until the OP has had the chance to edit the question?